# WHERE NOT EXISTS syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, session, syntax, where-clause

I have this code that does not work, and im not sure why...

```
if(isset($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['username'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $user = $_SESSION['username'];
  $query = $handler->query("INSERT INTO photolikes('User', 'Photo')
                            SELECT '$user', '$id'
                            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM photolikes WHERE User='$user' AND Photo=$id)");
}else{
}
```

Is just supposed to insert user and photo into a table if there is no such in there before... thanks for any help!

Comment: what you mean `doenst work`? give you one error? Should do something and do something different or doesnt do anything at all?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''User', 'Photo') SELECT ......

Comment: `INSERT INTO photolikes('User', 'Photo')`..... backticks around column names, not quote marks; and no `FROM tablename` in your first `SELECT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT` is missing the `FROM` clause which is required when a `WHERE` clause is used.

That's the problem.

There's a couple of ways to fix it.

For a quick fix, you can add  **`FROM DUAL`** before the **`WHERE`**.

---

If you don't like your MySQL queries looking like they are Oracle queries, you can use an inline view as a rowsource.

In place of **`FROM DUAL`** you could use **`FROM (SELECT 1) i`**.

That's the less-Oracle-more-MySQL-like way of fixing it. That's how I would do it.

You could also reference any table or view that you are guaranteed returns exactly one row. (It can't be zero rows, and it can't be two rows.

---

A couple other notes:

In MySQL, identifiers (for example column names) can be escaped with backtick characters, but not single quotes. Identifiers only need to be escaped if they contain characters that aren't allowed (in unescaped identifiers) or if the identifier conflicts with a reserved word.

```
 INSERT INTO photolikes(`User`, `Photo`)
                        ^    ^  ^     ^
```

Also, the code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Potentially unsafe values that are incorporated into the text of a SQL statement should be properly escaped. But an even better pattern is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Comment: @Den, you can not use `WHERE` without `FROM`. So you need a "table" for the `FROM` clause which has exactly one row, even though you don't read any data from it.

Comment: @Den:  DUAL is a dummy table name available in MySQL.  From the MySQL Reference Manual... "You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced:

DUAL is purely for the convenience of people who require that all SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced."  [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: Another solution would be to create a unique index `(User, Photo)` (which OP should do anyways) and use something like  `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY SET Id = Id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO photolikes(`User`, `Photo`)
     SELECT '$user', '$id'
     FROM <someTable>
     ^^^^ you miss the FROM
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id 
                       FROM photolikes  -- Here you didnt forget.
                       WHERE User='$user' AND Photo=$id)")
```

Comment: `someTable` could be a dummy subselect like `(select 1) dummy`

Comment: Changed the code to:("INSERT INTO photolikes(User, Photo)
                            SELECT '$user', $id FROM photo
                            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM photolikes WHERE User='$user' AND Photo='$id')");
Now it makes the same thing 10 times...

Comment: and is working after the change? you also need change `'User', 'Photo'` For `\`User\`, \`Photo\``

Comment: @Den: you're getting multiple rows inserted because the SELECT statement is returning multiple rows. Just use a rowsource that is guaranteed to return *exactly* one row, such as an inline view (derived table) or the special "DUAL" table.